# To solve the given partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2y$$

Now if I integrate above equation with respect to x then with respect to y then

$z_x=\frac{yx^3}{3}+a$ &

$z_y=\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+b$ (please correct me here if I am wrong)

Then how should I proceed to find solution.

Comment: The equation took the partial derivative in terms of $y$, then it took the partial derivative in terms of $x$. How would you reverse that process?

Comment: I am not sure about the method I used. A Kind request for you to correct  me. Thanks

Comment: The function $a$ can depend on $y$, $b$ can depend on $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2y\\\implies\text{Integrating w.r.t. $x$};z_y=\frac{x^3y}{3}+g(y),\ \ \ \text{where g is function of $y $ alone}\\\implies\text{Integrating w.r.t. y}\ \ \ z=\frac{x^3y^2}{6}+\int g(y)dy+c_1\end{align*}$$

Similarly, reversing the order of integration gives us $z=\frac{x^3y^2}{6}+\int f(x) dx+c_2$, where f is a function of $x$ alone. Equating the two expressions for $z$, we obtain, $z=\frac{x^3y^2}{6}+\text{constant}$ . Note that constant here implies a sum of pure functions of $x$ and $y$ alone and a real number.